# ClientHttpRequestInterceptor intercept method calling sequence?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Is the intercept method of ClientHttpRequestInterceptor called before the connection is acquired from the rest template connection pool or after?

Comment: Do you mean "thread pool" instead of "connection pool"?

Comment: I mean the rest connection pool which has the maxConnPerRoute and the maxConnTotal properties(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager)

Answer (score 1):

If you do nothing in the interceptor, then no HTTP call will be initiated, which means that a connection will not be acquired.

The code that makes the HTTP call is in `InterceptingClientHttpRequest`:

```
    private class InterceptingRequestExecution implements ClientHttpRequestExecution {

        private final Iterator<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> iterator;

        public InterceptingRequestExecution() {
            this.iterator = interceptors.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse execute(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            if (this.iterator.hasNext()) {
                ClientHttpRequestInterceptor nextInterceptor = this.iterator.next();
                return nextInterceptor.intercept(request, body, this);
            }
            else {
                HttpMethod method = request.getMethod();
                Assert.state(method != null, "No standard HTTP method");
                ClientHttpRequest delegate = requestFactory.createRequest(request.getURI(), method);
                request.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> delegate.getHeaders().addAll(key, value));
                if (body.length > 0) {
                    if (delegate instanceof StreamingHttpOutputMessage) {
                        StreamingHttpOutputMessage streamingOutputMessage = (StreamingHttpOutputMessage) delegate;
                        streamingOutputMessage.setBody(outputStream -> StreamUtils.copy(body, outputStream));
                    }
                    else {
                        StreamUtils.copy(body, delegate.getBody());
                    }
                }
                return delegate.execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, all interceptors are iterated to invoke `intercept`.

In general, in your `intercept method`, you need to execute the request (if you don't want to block it).

Suppose you have two interceptors:

```
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    rest.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("first interceptor enter");
        ClientHttpResponse execute = execution.execute(request, body);
        System.out.println(execute.getStatusCode() + " In first interceptor");
        System.out.println("first interceptor exit");
        return execute;
      }
    }, new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("second interceptor enter");
        ClientHttpResponse execute = execution.execute(request, body);
        System.out.println(execute.getStatusCode() + " In second interceptor");
        System.out.println("second interceptor exit");
        return execute;
      }
    }));
    return rest.getForObject("https://stackoverflow.com/", String.class);

// output:
first interceptor enter
second interceptor enter
200 OK In second interceptor
second interceptor exit
200 OK In first interceptor
first interceptor exit
```

The flow here is:

1. The interceptor method of the first interceptor(`interceptor A`) is called.
2. When `interceptor A` executes `execution.execute(request, body)`, second interceptor(`interceptor A`) is called.
3. When `interceptor B` executes `execution.execute(request, body)`, since there are no interceptors left, it will eventually make an HTTP call by `requestFactory.createRequest(request.getURI(), method)` . (In this method, a connection will be acquired as you say).